# google apps script: remove and restore protection

Tags: google-apps-script, range, spreadsheet-protection

I have a spreadsheet that is editable by everyone with a protected sheet with some ranges unprotected.

I want cells that can be altered by a script run by any user (from a menu), but **not** manually.

When I run the script not as the owner it gives an error message when I try to temporarily remove the protection.

Comment: The weird thing is, that anyone can access the script file and so hack the code to alter the protection.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no easy way to do this, because functions run from the menu is always executed as "user at the keyboard".

One workaround is to publish a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) to always "Execute as" Owner. This web app will then write to protected ranges on `doPost()`. The function linked to Menu UI will then use [`UrlFetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) to POST to the published Web App. You can also use some basic authentication with a password/randomly generated numbers to reject requests from outside your script.

Also, If you don't trust editors not to mess with your bound script, It's better to publish it as a private add-on, where the source code is not easily accessible.